# "La libertà è (la/una) possibilità di essere sé stessi": differenza tra le frasi con e senza l'articolo

Tags: difference, articles

> La libertà è possibilità di essere sé stessi.

o

> La libertà è una possibilità di essere sé stessi.

o

> La libertà è la possibilità di essere sé stessi.

Qual è la differenza tra queste frasi?
Qual è  la versione giusta?

Comment: “Qual è“, non *“Qual'è.”

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE!

Comment: Riguardo alla tua ultima domanda, credo non sia possibile risponderla senza una tua spiegazione su cosa vuoi esprimere con la frase.

Comment: Io non lo so, ho visto questa frase su Facebook e non riuscivo a capire perché non c'era nessun articolo. Ecco perché ho creato il thread.

Comment: Non trascurerei il fatto che ci sono anche le tre frasi senza l’articolo davanti a *libertà* e che possono dare sfumature diverse.

Answer (score 2):

'La' suggerisce che sia l'unica o almeno la principale possibilità, 'una' che sia una tra diverse possibilità, nella prima frase rimane indeterminata la questione, asserendo solamente la relazione (e assume un tono più astratto).